# Validate string without special characters

Tags: php, regex

i have a problem.

i want to get info about my string have other character in ( a-z A-Z 0-9 and - _ ) if my string have ordre its return false or not return true.

i hope i can get help to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your english. You want to know if it contains characters other than a-z, A-Z, 0-9, - and _?

If so, `preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/', $string)`

Comment: ereg is deprecated, preg_* should be used instead

Comment: oh, thank you. I use ereg_replace all the time. I'll have to kick that habbit :)

Answer (score 1):

i foundt my own way, but tanks to JasonWoof you make me on right way.

```
if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_-]/i", $this->page_shorttag))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to validate if a string only contains a-z A-Z 0-9 and -_. Right?

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*$/
```

...should work.

Comment: yes you understand my question right :) bot i don't work :/ its not validate curret. why i dont know. i hav try you and JasonWoof's answar.

Comment: this its my sample code
if ( !ereg( $this->page_shorttag , '[^a-zA-Z0-9\_-]') ) {} i use ø, æ and å to test this.